# Manwha where the firstborn has scales on her face. Is ignored in favour of her younger prettier sister

Tags: story-identification, manga

I saw this manwha/manga on an advert on Instagram. It showed the female main character, the oldest daughter, who was was born with scales on her face. I think she had black or brown hair, I'm not sure.

Afterwards, her mother gave birth to her sister and now her mother completely ignores the oldest and only gives attention to the youngest.

I don't know if it was a curse or not, or if it was historical, but I do vaguely recall them being in a palace.

Comment: Scales on her face as in '*lizard scales*'?

Comment: Possibly the same story? https://www.reddit.com/r/manhwa/comments/11p7ri2/can_someone_help_me_find_this_mahnwa/

Comment: Remember to mention where else you're looking - ["Reddit: Help me find this manga/ manhwa"](https://www.reddit.com/r/manga/comments/1b37t5j/help_me_find_this_manga_manhwa/)

Answer (score 2):

Older, ignored sister with scales on her face matches [The Admiral's Monstrous Wife](https://m.tapas.io/series/the-admirals-monstrous-wife/info), though her hair is white. I suspect it's the same manhwa as [ChocolateTop2853 asked about](https://www.reddit.com/r/manhwa/comments/11p7ri2/can_someone_help_me_find_this_mahnwa/), since the plot is that she's being married off to an admiral who is the leader of his people.

> They call her a monster… but to this admiral, she’s a sacred descendant of the sea! Rudia Flang has been mistreated her whole life, so when the emperor arranges her marriage to Alexander Cilia, war hero and the youngest admiral in history, she cowers in fear at the thought of marrying a violent seaman. As this ocean voyage treks on, she’s met with benevolence from the Sercilian Island people who, unbeknownst to her, find the scales glistening on her body far from the marking of a monster...

[image: "ahh, my face!!"]